# SQL Stored Procedure Parameter set to Uppercase

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to force a user's string input in a stored procedure to uppercase.  I tried writing `UPPER` prior to the `@parameterName` but I got a syntax error.  Is this possible? Would be it be better suited to convert the string to uppercase in the statement itself?  Here's the code to my SP where I was attempting to use `UPPER` in the parameter definition.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateEntries]
    UPPER @ENTRY_TYPE NVARCHAR(20) = '',
    UPPER @ENTRY_NAME NVARCHAR(50),
    @CLASS_TYPE_ID INT,
    @ENTRY_PRICE DEC(4,2),
    @ENTRY_DESCRIPT NVARCHAR(max),
    @PET_FRIENDLY BIT,
    @AGE_RESTRICTION BIT,
    @PRICE_RANGE_ID INT,
    @RESTAURANT_TYPE_ID INT NULL

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF @ENTRY_TYPE = 'ACTIVITY'
    BEGIN
        UPDATE ACTIVITY_DETAIL
        SET ACT_NAME = @ENTRY_NAME,
        ACT_PRICE = @ENTRY_PRICE, 
        ACT_DESCRIPT = @ENTRY_DESCRIPT, 
        ACT_DOG_FRIENDLY = @PET_FRIENDLY, 
        ACT_AGE_RESTRICTION = @AGE_RESTRICTION,
        ACT_PRICE_RANGE_ID = @PRICE_RANGE_ID
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.[ACTIVITY_DETAIL] WHERE ACT_NAME = @ENTRY_NAME);
    END

    IF @ENTRY_TYPE = 'BUSINESS'
    BEGIN
        UPDATE BUSINESS_DETAIL
        SET BUSINESS_NAME = @ENTRY_NAME,
        BUSINESS_PRICE = @ENTRY_PRICE, 
        BUSINESS_DESCRIPT = @ENTRY_DESCRIPT, 
        BUSINESS_DOG_FRIENDLY = @PET_FRIENDLY, 
        BUSINESS_PRICE_RANGE_ID = @PRICE_RANGE_ID
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.[BUSINESS_DETAIL] WHERE BUSINESS_NAME = @ENTRY_NAME);
    END

    IF @ENTRY_TYPE = 'HOTEL'
    BEGIN
        UPDATE HOTEL_DETAIL
        SET HOTEL_NAME = @ENTRY_NAME,
        HOTEL_PRICE = @ENTRY_PRICE, 
        HOTEL_DESCRIPT = @ENTRY_DESCRIPT, 
        HOTEL_PET_FRIENDLY = @PET_FRIENDLY, 
        HOTEL_PRICE_RANGE_ID = @PRICE_RANGE_ID
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.[HOTEL_DETAIL] WHERE HOTEL_NAME = @ENTRY_NAME);
    END

    IF @ENTRY_TYPE = 'RESTAURANT'
    BEGIN
        UPDATE RESTAURANT_DETAIL
        SET RESTAURANT_NAME = @ENTRY_NAME,
        RESTAURANT_PRICE_AVG = @ENTRY_PRICE, 
        RESTAURANT_DESCRIPT = @ENTRY_DESCRIPT, 
        RESTAURANT_DOG_FRIENDLY = @PET_FRIENDLY, 
        RESTAURANT_PRICE_RANGE_ID = @PRICE_RANGE_ID
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.[RESTAURANT_DETAIL] WHERE RESTAURANT_NAME = @ENTRY_NAME);
    END
END
```

Comment: You need to show us your code if you want is to help you with it.

Comment: Note SSMS is purely a Client UI, so is very rarely relevant to an SQL Server question.

Comment: @DaleK Added my code to my question.

Comment: You can't do this `UPPER @ENTRY_TYPE NVARCHAR(20) = ''`. By the way, where did you get that syntax from ?  You convert it in side the code of your stored procedure `SELECT @ENTRY_TYPE = UPPER(@ENTRY_TYPE);`

Comment: @Squirrel yup that's what I discovered which is why I was asking assistance on the best approach.  Figured it'd need to be defined in the statement itself, just wasn't sure what the syntax would be.  I'll give this a shot! Thank you!

Comment: SQL Server isn't *normally* case sensitive either, so unless you are using a case sensitive collation, you don't need to convert it to compare it.

Comment: [upper()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/upper-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is a function. So you used it like any other function

Comment: @DaleK ah that's actually super helpful.  The reason why I went down this path is because I wanted to join on, let's say HOTEL_NAME from HOTEL_DETAIL given the value entered in ENTRY_NAME.  I figured I'd need to clean up the data received in the SP in order to join properly to my HOTEL_DETAIL table. So regardless of the case of the string, SQL can join on two values when one record is capitalized and the other isn't?

Comment: @MichaelValdes why not try it and see?

Comment: It is generally a poor design to have a stored procedure do something different depending on a parameter. Given the pattern of repetition in the column names, seems like you have a normalization issue that is contributing to your problems and is leading/encouraging you to use this design.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPPER @ENTRY_TYPE NVARCHAR(20) = '',
UPPER @ENTRY_NAME NVARCHAR(50),
```

These are wrong.  No such usage.
@ENTRY_TYPE NVARCHAR(20) = '',
@ENTRY_NAME NVARCHAR(50),

```
SELECT @ENTRY_TYPE = UPPER(@ENTRY_TYPE);
SELECT @ENTRY_NAME = UPPER(@ENTITY_NAME);
```

Comment: Or simply `SET @ENTRY_TYPE = UPPER(@ENTRY_TYPE);`

Comment: He just want to convert the input value to an uppercase one.  And then do the check.

Comment: To be fair, OP only mention about comparing value in the comments, not in the initial question.

Comment: Sorry,  I would like to rollback my content from the "answer" part.  Is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean?